In Numbers, what determines ascending order?
In Numbers app, ascending order ranks a cell containing “A + B” before “A.” But I would like it to be ordered thus: “A,” “A + B,” “A + B + C,” “B,” “B + X,” etc. I could switch to descending order, but then that would reverse the alphabetizing of the entire list.
More concretely, I want a cell containing RAT to appear above a cell containing RAT + LIGHT, and I want that in turn to appear above RAT + LIGHT + TONE. But in ascending order the opposite is the case. I don’t understand why adding more information makes something appear higher on a list when it seems it should be lower. What am I missing?

What are your iOS and macOS versions and the respective Numbers versions? What are the language / region settings on your devices and, if different, the Numbers file you are working on? I have iOS 16.7.8 and macOS 14.5 and Numbers 14.1 installed on both. Both Numbers apps sort "A" before "A + B" under ascending order.

Thanks. I have iOS 17.5.1, MacOS 14.5, Numbers 14.1. English / United States.
